# How to disable logback logstash appender when host is offline?

Tags: spring-boot, logstash, logback

I use a Spring Boot Application with logback-logstash. Also I use the ELK Stack.

In my logback-spring.xml

```
<appender name="logstash" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
    <destination>https://mykibana.url</destination>....
```

I configure logback to establish a connection to logstash, everything works fine. Sometimes I dont have an internet connection to my logstash server. For e.g. when I work offline in a train. And I dont want to boot up an entire ELK Stack localy.

My console is flooded with exceptions like

```
00:37:15,429 |-WARN in net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender[logstash] - 
    at java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
```

Is it possible to configure logback like:

if
connection possible connect
else
do not use logstash appender

or

try 3 times than give up